# Why is the answer variable in this While Loop example?

Tags: ruby

I am learning ruby and computer science topics for the first time.  I am reading through the book "Learn to program" By Chris Pine and have a question about an example.

Here is the code:

```
def ask(question)                           # new method with paramater question
  while true                                # starts a loop
    puts question                           # puts the question on the screen
    reply = gets.chomp.downcase             # gets the question and makes it lower case

    if (reply == "yes" || reply == "no")    # if reply was yes or no 
      if reply == "yes"                     # nested if statement if yes answer == true
        answer = true                       # WHAT??
      else                                  # the else of the second if
        answer = false                      # WHAT?? why do we care about answer??
      end
      break                                 # Breaks the Loop
    else                                    # the else of the 1st if 
      puts ' Please answer "yes" or "no".'
    end
  end
  answer                                    # Why is answer here?
end
```

My question is why do we need "answer"? I don't see how it is having any impact on the loop. The while loop is set to true not answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
end
 answer                                     #Why is answer here?
end
```

It is there to return the result of `answer`(either `true` or `false`) from the method `ask`.

> My question is why do we need "answer"?

`answer` is needed as per your example to hold the Boolean value which is to be returned when method execution will be completed. Your `while` loop is an infinite loop,which can only be broken by the `break` statement,when `reply` will be having either `'yes'` or `'no'` vlaue.

Comment: Thanks! I see that but why do we really even care about that at all? It doesn't impact our loop in anyway does it? or really anything? Could we just have answer = 5 if it is yes, and answer = 4 if it is no?

Comment: I somewhat see it. How come you don't predefine answer = true outside of the loop, then set While answer(which is now true)? Also what is the break then doing in the loop? I thought that's what was breaking the loop?

Comment: @Babai, although accepted, your answer is incorrect. `answer` is not needed to exit the infinite while loop. That could have also been achieved by returning `true` or `false` directly, thus eliminating the `answer` variable.

Comment: **Down-voter** what's your problem? What's wrong with this answer ?

Answer (score 4):

Ruby returns the last statement it executes.  In effect, it's the same as writing

```
return answer;
```

...in a language like C or Java.

Comment: Thats the next exercise is to replace answer with return.  I'm just trying to grasp the significance of answer? I don't really see how it is connecting or effecting anything in my loop? is answer breaking my while loop? or is the "break" breaking my loop?

Comment: @Codey: Putting `answer` at the end of the method has nothing to do with your loop.  The `break` is breaking your loop, allowing you to get to the statement `answer` -- I reformatted the code in your question to visually emphasize this.  Ruby's default behavior is to return the value of the last expression evaluated in a method, so you don't need an explicit `return ...` statement as found in many other languages.  When that last expression is `answer`, the current value of `answer` becomes the return value of the `ask(question)` method.